# SQL Beginner trying to insert data on tables

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have started my journey in learning SQL and right I am having trouble creating and inserting data into tables. Here is the code that I have tried, I get an error message saying that there aren't enough values. I am using Oracle.

```
Create table project
(
    proj_id number(10),
    medic_name varchar2(10),
    purpose varchar2(12),
    start_date date,
    end_date date,
    pi_id null,

    CONSTRAINT pkprojid primary key (proj_id),
    CONSTRAINT fkproject foreign key (pi_id) references researcher
);

alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy';

Insert into project values (PR001, 'Medic1', 'heart', '09/01/2017', '07/31/2019'); 
Insert into project values (PR002, 'Medic1', 'diabetes', '10/01/2016', '07/31/2020);
Insert into project values (PR003, 'Medic3', 'lung', '11/1/2014', '12/31/2020');
Insert into project values (PR004, 'Medic3', 'blood', '01/10/2017', '07/31/2019');
Insert into project values (PR005, 'Medic5', 'blood', '07/10/2018', '01/31/2020');

alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy';
```

Comment: PRxxx is not a number. And a single quote is missing in line 2 after 2020

Answer (score 5):

> Insert into project values (PR001, 'Medic1', 'heart', '09/01/2017', '07/31/2019');

Issues:

- Your table has 6 columns, you are only passing 5 for insert; it seems like you are missing last column (`pi_id`), hence the error message that you are getting. If you want to skip the last column (which is possible since it is declared as nullable), you can explictly list the column when inserting
- first column (`proj_id`) is of `number` datatype; `PR001` is not a number (neither a string, since it is not quoted: this is a syntax error); did you mean `1` instead? Or, if you want to insert string values, you need to change the datatype of column `proj_id` to `varchar(N)` (`N` being the maximum length of the string, in bytes).

Here is an `insert` statement that should work for your current table definition:

```
insert into project(proj_id, medic_name, purpose, start_date, end_date) 
values (1, 'Medic1', 'heart', '09/01/2017', '07/31/2019');
```

Note: there is a missing quote at the end of the date on the second `insert` statement; I assume that this is a typo.